# Apache Airflow cannot execute any DAG - why?

Tags: python, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I'm trying to execute some airflow DAGs on localhost but non works.
I get always the same error:

```
[2022-11-15, 20:18:35 CET] {taskinstance.py:1383} INFO - Executing <Task(BashOperator): get_datetime> on 2022-11-15 19:18:29.749895+00:00
[2022-11-15, 20:18:35 CET] {standard_task_runner.py:55} INFO - Started process 8406 to run task
[2022-11-15, 20:18:35 CET] {standard_task_runner.py:82} INFO - Running: ['airflow', 'tasks', 'run', 'first_dag', 'get_datetime', 'manual__2022-11-15T19:18:29.749895+00:00', '--job-id', '79', '--raw', '--subdir', 'DAGS_FOLDER/first_dag.py', '--cfg-path', '/var/folders/8t/ll6ysglj0nj5dq53clwnnsg40000gn/T/tmpb3a0nyuj']
[2022-11-15, 20:18:35 CET] {standard_task_runner.py:83} INFO - Job 79: Subtask get_datetime
[2022-11-15, 20:18:35 CET] {standard_task_runner.py:100} ERROR - Failed to execute job 79 for task get_datetime ([Errno 2] No such file or directory: **'/var/folders/8t/ll6ysglj0nj5dq53clwnnsg40000gn/T/tmpb3a0nyuj'; 8406)**
```

I'm working on Mac with M1. What is important 'airflow tasks test' works.
Please advise something..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you have a distributed Airflow executor (Celery or Kubernetes), and your dag folder is only mounted to the scheduler process, but not the workers. Airflow scheduler and workers runs the dag script for each operation on the task, so in your case, the workers doesn't find the dag script and it fail.

If you are using docker compose, you can check if the dag folder is mounted to all the containers and if not you need to add it.

Comment: Hi Hussein, thanks for answer. 
I’m using 2.4.2 version of airflow installed on my mac by pip3. Is it possible to change or set workers appropriately, for example in config file ?